# Basics of job applying

Tags: cover-letter

There are different methods companies follow to help them select their prospective candidate.

One of them is online job applications.

In this we have two options where, one is to go through a set of instructions and upload the resume and cover letter and so on. In the other we are given a specific career department email to send our resume to.

Question. If its the second case, where we are supposed to send in our resume. Where does the cover letter go? Is it the body of the email , if yes then is there any necessary to add an attachment of cover letter and a resume with this email (assuming the cover letter has a company logo) ?

Comment: I mean if I want to have a logo on my cover letter. Do I add that to the email body ?

Comment: There is a chance that the e-mail is to an automated system that may just discard the body of the e-mail is something to note here as a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

> Where does the cover letter go?

Attaching both the cover letter and resume as separate documents allows you to completely control the formatting and logo.

Alternatively, you could attach a single document which includes both your cover letter and resume together.

I've usually just attached the resume, and made the body of the email become my cover letter. But I have never used a logo on a cover letter, so that may not meet your needs.

Comment: the logo is not really important, so if I just have the email body as my cover letter, there is no need to attach it again right ?